# prevent temporary popup from closing onmouseover

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a text in a table that shows a popup text onmouseover, and this popup disappears 1 second after onmouseout.

I want this popup not to disappear if the mouse is moved over the popup (that is, if the mouse is moved away from the original table text but over the popup). An example of what i want to achieve can be seen in http://www.pnas.org/content/current , scroll down a little bit and place the mouse over an article title.
Can I include a function on the popup to prevent its closing?
I know that almost everything can be achieved, but I'm an newbie amateur, so dont waste your time if the solution is complex.

My code for the popup:

```
var popup;
function lopen() {
if (this.element == null) {
  this.element = document.createElement('div');
  this.element.id = "myPopup";
  this.element.innerHTML = "new text";
  this.element.style = "position: absolute; top: 650px; left: 400px; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: #ccc;";
}
document.body.appendChild(this.element);
} 

var timeoutID;
function delayedlclose() {
   timeoutID = window.setTimeout(lclose, 1000);
}  
function lclose () {
   document.body.removeChild(this.element);
}
```

The link for displaying the popup is in a html table:

```
<tr><td><a onmouseover="lopen()" onmouseout="delayedlclose()">Show</td></tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

you could move your `onmouseout` event handler from the `<a>` to the `<div id='myPopup'>`